# Find intersection of two images in C#

Tags: c#, image, intersection

I have two images (A and B) and would like to know the rectangle intersection of the images. The images represent scrolled screen content, and I would only like the exclusive value of the images with no intersections. So A represents a capture, then B represents the same screen area but scrolled some % of the content, with additional content at the bottom. but because the scroll will not always represent an entire scroll of content (at the end, for instance)

So basically if B was only a partially scrolled view of the content, I want to reduce B so it does not contain any image data that's present in A; so when I merge A and B (and any other scrolls prior to A) they do not contain duplicate data.

This is my example image representing A and B stitched together; as you can see the content is duplicated.

[image]

Comment: This is too broad. What have you tried, if anything?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to know what have you tried already?

Comment: I am capturing on-screen Windows in Windows 10. I've been using Windows Automation Framework, and I've tried interrogating the ScrollPattern of the content in question to estimate its height based on the VerticalScrollPercent and VerticalViewSize. However it appears that the math on those two values, while doubles, is imprecise, and doesn't allow me to smart crop.

I haven't tried image manipulating which is why I opened this topic; I'm unsure if I can just .Intersect a 2D byte array. I'm looking for approaches and don't need precise code. assume A and B are C# Bitmaps

Answer (score 1):

There is some ambiguity here since there could be multiple intersections. By that I mean there could a 1 pixel high intersection as well as a 100 pixel high intersection. One way to resolve that ambiguity is to take the greatest intersection possible between the two images. Here's a brute force method. I'll assume the two screenshots have the same dimensions `w` x `h`.

```
Compare  each of `h` rows of A to B.
Perform the same comparison on `h-1` rows with A's y coordinates offset by +1 (down 1).
Perform the same comparison on `h-2` rows with A's y coordinates offset by +2 (down 2).
...
```

Whenever the comparison succeeds, return that offset. That is the Y coordinate of A that should be stitched to the top of B.

The main issue here is performance. The worst case time is pretty bad (width * height * height) but that's if every pixel compares identical until the last one, for every row. By returning early as soon as one pixel doesn't match the performance might be practically good enough.

### Comparing with memcp

Here's an easy and fast way to compare your images starting at a given Y offset.

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int memcmp(IntPtr b1, IntPtr b2, long count);
static bool compareIntersection(int width, int height, int yOffset, IntPtr a, IntPtr b)
{
    int bytesPerPixel = 4; // this needs to be set to reflect your image format
    int bytesToRead = (height - yOffset) * width * bytesPerPixel;
    IntPtr aStart = a + yOffset * width * bytesPerPixel;
    return 0 == memcmp(aStart, b, bytesToRead);
}
```

The arguments to the function are the width of the image, height of the image, the y offset in A, and pointers into the beginning of each bitmap's memory. You can get those pointers by using Bitmap.LockBits and then BitmapData.Scan0.

The code is untested so it could have problems.

Comment: the greatest intersection is indeed what I am looking for. and in actual use the heights of the compared captures will always be the same. I am comparing images less than 1000 pixels high. so I will be starting the comparison always from the top of B... so instead of comparing every row in B to every row in A, I should be able to compare the first row in B and find that row in A. If it does not exist then there is no overlap. If it does exist compare next row of B to next row of A. continue until next row in B != next row in A.

Comment: then from a more practical standpoint, fast comparison of pixel rows? I see the C# BitmapData class but it returns a single-dimension array of bitmap bytes.

Comment: essentially I should only ever scan the A image with the first row of B once, and as soon as I find a matching row I am 'locked in' and can proceed row by row across both images until I see non-matching rows, and record/return/crop the offset. Complexity won't be so bad, O(2n) is the worst case when A matches B exactly and n is count of rows of pixels.

Comment: I threw some untested code in there for one way to go about comparing the images